# Get auth_token from enterprise account configured for SSO

Tags: box-api

I am trying to authenticate through an external application using the API. Unfortunately, our enterprise accounts are configured to redirect authentication back to our internal AD through SAML to use SSO. Is there any way to configure a "service account" or at least get my enterprise account to authenticate so i can receive a auth_token to run my nightly processes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Box API's standard authentication process, you should be able to obtain an auth_token as an SSO user.  The process involves your app directing the user to Box, which can direct the user to one's SSO endpoint.  After logging into the SSO endpoint, the user can connect your app to Box.

Once you obtain an auth_token, you can hold onto that auth_token to run processes in the background.  Users only have to connect your application once, and you can run nightly processes from there.

Comment: Additional Question (4 years later): What if the user had Box credentials prior to the switch to SSO, but does not have an SSO login (integrated apps have service type accounts which will likely have been left out of AD). With that account continue to be able to refresh their token without being redirected to the SSO?